# Remove/Replace all scripts on AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to replace/reload every script when I send an AJAX request which is called every time you click on a link (to load the page).

```
var containerClass = ".container",
    container = $(containerClass),
    scripts;     

$.ajax({                                                             
    url: href,
    cache: false,
    success: function (result) {
        scripts = $("body").find("script[src]");

        if(scripts.length) {
            scripts.detach();
            scripts.remove();
        }

        scripts.each(function() {
            var text = $("body").text(),
                node = document.createElement("script");

                 if(!$(this)[0].async) node.async = false;

                node.src = $(this).attr("src");

                node.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
                document.body.appendChild(node);
                console.log("Added");
        });

        container.html($(result).filter(containerClass).html());
    }
});
```

The problem here is that `.detach()` and `.remove()` is not behaving as I expected them to behave - instead every time a request is sent, the amount of scripts seem to double: e.g. 1st request it prints 12 "Added" messages in the console, but the next request it prints 24, and the next 48 and so on.

How can this be achieved in the best/most efficient way possible?

Comment: The issue is because the `scripts` variable still holds the elements in memory, even though you've removed them from the DOM.

Comment: I guess you actually want to use a MutationObserver inside of these scripts to detect when the AJAX call succeeded or you attach listeners.

Comment: As @Rory McCrossan points out remove the element from the `scripts` array also when you are removing it from the DOM, before the `.each` that iterates over that same array

Comment: What is the point of inserting `src` url as text in new script element? What exactly are you trying to accomplish at a higher level?

Comment: Looks like an XY Problem - what are you trying to achieve by removing and replacing all the scripts?  Is it something you could more easily achieve using a `reset()` function to restore variables to their start point?  Or not use ajax to load the page.

Comment: I'm using this when I'm using the history API mode. Because I have to actually load the page somehow, but if I don't reapply all scripts, they are not loaded when you get the new page.

Comment: They are loaded, they're just not run when you go back using history API.  You need to find how to run them/a script on history back.